# Performance issue with Remote Partition in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Our application designed with spring batch application. 
so , the problem is while sending messages from master instance to JMS MQ, received following error.

Scenario is

1)  300K data,
2)  created 50 partitions,
3)  2 instances -> 1(Master/slave), 1(slave)

```
 logLevel=WARN thread=[workerJmsContainer-20] 
 category=jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer message - Execution 
 of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set. 
             java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

"VM Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fa87cb0f800 nid=0x5b56 runnable 

 "GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fa87c5c8000 nid=0x5b31 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fa87c603000 nid=0x5b32 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fa87c044800 nid=0x5b33 runnable 

 "GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fa87c5c6800 nid=0x5b34 runnable 

  Heap
    object space 699392K, 51% used
   Metaspace       used 89620K, capacity 92552K, committed 93164K, reserved 1130496K
   class space    used 10647K, capacity 11144K, committed 11264K, reserved 1048576K
```

verified with MQ team, there was not limit crossed in Queue and no failure from their side.

These are the setting in yml file

```
 spring:
   taskExecutor:
     corePoolSize: 50
     maxPoolSize: 100
     queueCapacity: 1000
   partition:
     gridSize: 50
     ChunkSize: 1000
     concurrentConsumers: 25
```

Comment: Where is the log message originating from. Is it coming from the master or from the worker

Comment: What is JMS MQ is it IBM mqseries or what MQ provider is it ? Some MQ providers are first arranging messages in a client queue before crossing the network boundary.

Comment: log message originating from both master and slave. JMS MQ is IBM MQ series. we have dedicated queues for our application. we have verified the size of queue also. it was exceed.

Comment: we have set few variables on jobExecution with large number of data. which we have required in multiple steps. would it be cause ?   ex:- Count=399625

Comment: Yes, that could be the reason of your OOM.

Comment: Issue is still there after reducing size of variable .